# Excel VBA making user selected range variables permanent

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script that is converting a Julian Date to a Gregorian Date.  I am supposed to be able to click on a range that contains my Julian Date, then select on a range where I'd like to insert my Gregorian Date.  The only problem is that once I set the first selected range as JD (Julian Date), I can't seem to assign a new selected range.

For instance if I select B:B as my range of JD, then JD = 2.

Then if I select D:D for my range of GD (Gregorian Date), then GD should = 4, but it still equals 2.  I'm not sure what else is going to error out after I get through with this part, but I'm stuck here for now.  Can anyone provide any insight?  Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub Julian_to_Gregorian()
    Dim rng As Range, col As Range, cols As Range, arr
    Dim sht As Worksheet, shet As Worksheet, hdr As Long, yn As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim dest As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
                Prompt:="Please select the column that contains the Julian Date. " & vbNewLine & _
                        " (e.g. Column A or Column B)", _
                Title:="Select Julian Date Range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    jd = Selection.Column
    'pjd = jd.Column

    hdr = MsgBox("Does your selection contain a header?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Header Option")

    Set dest = Application.InputBox( _
                Prompt:="Please select the column that the Gregorian Date will be placed in. " & vbNewLine & _
                        "(A new column will be inserted in this location, preserving the current data in this location.)", _
                Title:="Select Destination Range", Type:=8)
      gd = Selection.Column
     If dest Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
     'gd = Selection.Column

     Set sht = dest.Parent
     Set shet = rng.Parent


     On Error GoTo 0
     'yn = MsgBox("Do you want to insert a new column here?" & vbNewLine & _
      '           "(Choosing 'No' will replace the current cells in your selected range." & vbNewLine & _
       '          "All data in this range will be permanently deleted.)", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Destination Range Options")


    LastRow = shet.Cells(Rows.Count, jd).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'With Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, 2 + Range("B1"))).EntireColumn
     With Cells(1, gd).EntireColumn
     .Insert Shift:=xlToRight
     End With
    'gd.EntireColumn.Insert xlRight
    gd = gd - 1
    For i = 2 To LastRow
    Cells(i, gd).Value = "=DATE(IF(0+(LEFT(" & Cells(i, jd) & ",2))<30,2000,1900)+LEFT(" & Cells(i, jd) & ",2),1,RIGHT(" & Cells(i, pjd) & ",3))"

    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not test the rest of your code, but to get the correct columns:

1. replace

`jd = Selection.Column` with `jd = rng.Column`

2. replace

`gd = Selection.Column`with `gd = dest.Column`

The reason your code didn't work was simple: The selection you activate during your prompts are no "real" selections in the sheet, they are only valid for the prompt. After the prompt, the selection from before the prompts will be active again and thus, jd and gd would always be equal to the column of the cell selected before executing the macro.

Comment: So it seems that jd and gd are being recognized as the user selected ranges; however, there seems to be an issue with them still.  

After inserting a column in gd (thus changing gd to gd + 1), I change gd to  'gd = gd-1'.  Then in cells i, gd  i enter the formula above; however, it doesn't seem to be doing anything at all.  after the macro runs, I'm left with a blank column.  DO you have any ideas regarding that?

Even if not, thanks again for getting me past the errors!

Comment: I'm not really sure what this formula is supposed to do, but if it outputs nothing, maybe the if clause was not met. Why do you alter gd after inserting a column? It should stay the same, so try to get rid of `gd = gd-1`

Comment: I was under the impression that if GD was 3, and you insert a column at GD, then GD becomes 4 (since that data slides over).  Maybe I'm completely misunderstanding though

Comment: Even if it would be that way, it should be `gd = gd + 1` instead. But since gd is the destination column, that should stay the same. Have you tried the formula before by manually inserting it into a cell?